# open mssql stored procedure from excel 2007 VBA and get data to excel

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I try to call a stored procedure from excel 2007 by VBA. I would like get return from stored procedure into excel sheet. But I get the 
'run-time 3074 Operation is not allowed when the object is closed' on Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset objMyRecordset

below is the code I write:

```
Option Explicit

Sub OpenConnection()

Dim objMyConn As ADODB.Connection
Dim objMyCmd As ADODB.Command
Dim objMyRecordset As ADODB.Recordset
Dim ConnectionString As String
Dim CommandText As String

Set objMyConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set objMyCmd = New ADODB.Command
Set objMyRecordset = New ADODB.Recordset



ConnectionString = "Provider=sqloledb;Data Source=abcsql,1433;Initial Catalog=admin;User Id=sa;Password=1234abcd;"
objMyConn.Open ConnectionString


Set objMyCmd.ActiveConnection = objMyConn
CommandText = "exec [admin].[dbo].[sp_weekly]"
objMyCmd.CommandType = adCmdText

Set objMyRecordset.Source = objMyCmd
objMyRecordset.Open 

Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset objMyRecordset

end
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify that you are calling a procedure as follows:

...

```
Set objMyCmd.ActiveConnection = objMyConn
CommandText = "sp_weekly"
objMyCmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
```

...

Comment: still get the same problem. fyi, adCmdStoredProc is 4

Comment: What does the stored procedure look like?

Comment: the stored procedure return a select statement